# Finding the $n$th coefficient closed form of a function

Tags: discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

I am working with the generating function $f(x) = \frac{1}{1-5x^4}$.
In terms of factoring, I would imagine it would be most reasonable to
factor $1-5x^4$, and the use partial fractions to get each individual term.
We see that, $1-5x^4 = -(5x^4 - 1) = -(\sqrt{5}x^2 - 1)(\sqrt{5}x^2 + 1),$
and thus
$$\frac{1}{1-5x^4} = \frac{A}{-(\sqrt{5}x^2-1)} + \frac{B}{\sqrt{5}x^2 + 1}.$$
$$\implies 1 = A(\sqrt{5}x^2+1) + B(-(\sqrt{5}x^2-1))$$
We see that when $x = \frac{1}{5^{1/4}},$
$$\implies 1= A(2) \implies \frac{1}{2} = A$$,
and thus
$$\implies 1 = \frac{1}{2}(\sqrt{5}x^2+1) + B(-(\sqrt{5}x^2-1))$$
$$\implies \frac{1-\frac{1}{2}(\sqrt{5}x^2+1)}{-(\sqrt{5}x^2-1)} = B.$$

However, this gives me a rather difficult pair of terms to try to algebraically
derive a closed form for the $n$th coefficient. Is there a simpler way to
solve for this closed form? Any recommendations would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest approach is start with the geometric series
$$ \frac{1}{1-z}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}z^n $$
and replace $z$ with $5x^4$. This leads to
$$ \frac{1}{1-5x^4}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}5^nx^{4n}$$
Since the original series is valid for $|z|<1$, this series is valid for $5|x|^4<1$, i.e. $|x|<5^{-\frac{1}{4}}$.